# Sum of numbers separated with comma

Tags: javascript, beginner, html

I am very new to HTML and I've decided to attempt to put what I know into an HTML page that allows you to enter any amount of numbers, separated by commas, and would display the sum of all the numbers below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Sum of two numbers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Enter any amount of numbers separated by a comma:</h1>
  <input id="nums" type="text" required="required" />
  <button onclick="sum()">Get sum</button>
  <h3 id="sum"></h3>

  <script lang="javascript">
    function sum() {
      sumofnums = 0;
      nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");
      for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sumofnums += parseInt(nums[i]);
      }
      document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sumofnums;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Are there any bad practices in my code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### HTML or XHTML? Which version? Be clear.

Your file is ambiguous. The usage of the empty element tag syntax `<input ... */>*` suggests (not mandates) that it's XHTML, whereas the absence of a namespace declaration suggests its not.

I recommend that documents are always clear about whether they're HTML or XHTML. And I recommend XHTML because parsing XHTML is simpler than parsing HTML, and HTML5 is defined in a way that XHTML5 documents are (more or less) a subset of HTML5 documents. The keyword is *polyglot* syntax.

Maybe in your context it's clear, but there is not sufficient information for us, the reviewers, whether your server would serve it as `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`.

Note that `<!DOCTYPE html>` does not sufficiently declare HTML5. The HTML5 specification says that an HTML5 document should have a doctype declaration of the form `<!DOCTYPE html>`. But it does not declare that everything that has such a doctype declaration is HTML5. It also does not (and cannot) prevent any other specification from also using the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration for some other variant of HTML than HTML5. Furthermore, it permits XHTML5 to also use the very same `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration. See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#writing-xhtml-documents).

I recommend to use the XHTML5 with the polyglot syntax, which is the "common subset" of HTML5 and XHTML5. It is basically HTML5 parsable with an XML parser. I recommend this for multiple reasons.

- The parsing rules of XML are simpler, therefore automated processing of documents with tools such as XSLT is simpler / possible with the XML syntax.
- You can create DTDs or XML Schemas that further validate your syntax. XML Schema with XML namespaces allows you to validate the mix of different XML-based languages such as for example XHTML and SVG within a single document.

(It's a pitty that the guys of WhatWG are so ignorant towards XML and its capabilities. It's a pitty that the guys of WhatWG had to reinvent the wheel and declare HTML5 as a markup language of its own right besides SGML and XML. That was completely unnecessary and it only confuses people, as we can see with this discussion about the `<!DOCTYPE>`.)

### Declare encoding

It's recommended to always declare the encoding. And the encoding should be declared within the first 1024 bytes.

There are 4 ways how the server can declare the encoding of a (X)HTML document to the client:

- HTTP `Content-Type` header: The server would send something like `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` or `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8` to the client.
- XML declaration (only for XHTML, not HTML), as the first line of the document: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.
- Meta element declaring the `Content-Type`, like this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` resp. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />`
- Meta element declaring the `Charset`, like this: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

See [this](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) for more information.

### Document Outline

The outline of your document looks like this:

- Enter any amount of numbers separated by a comma:

  - (level skipped)

    - (empty headline)

I doubt that this outline makes sense.

Keep in mind that `<h1/>`, `<h2/>` etc. are for headlines. If you just want a paragraph with big text but without the semantics of a headline, use a normal paragraph instead and style it with CSS.

Also, skipping levels is not recommended. For a `<h*N*/>` element, the next heading should have a level not greater than `N+1`.

### How to declare the scripting language

The correct way to declare the scripting language on a `<script/>` element is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ...
</script>
```

If you know that the User Agent supports HTML5 or behaves as expected, you can actually omit the declaration of the scripting language:

> [The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)

The `lang` attribute is actually meant for describing the content language, like this:

```
<h1 lang="en">Hi, <span lang="es">Hola</span>, <span lang="de">Hallo und <span lang="de-BY">Servus</span></span>!</h1>
```

What you did, actually declares the contents of the `<script/>` element to be in a *non-existent natural language named JavaScript*.

### Naming Conventions

Because JavaScript and Java were somehow born together, they follow identical naming conventions. Which means, we also use `camelCase` for variables and functions in JavaScript.

Your variable `sumofnums` should be named `sumOfNums`.

### Local vs Global Variables

In JavaScript, whenever you assign a variable without declaration, it is implicitly global. Local variables need to be declared explicitly, using the `var` keyword.

You should declare your variables, like this:

```
var sumOfNums = 0;
var nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");
```

The same is true for `i`.
It can be declared at the `for`-loop, like in Java:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  sumOfNums += parseInt(nums[i]);
}
```

However, be aware that scopes in JavaScript are only global or function-local. Blocks do not define new scopes for variables.

### User Input Validation

If the user inputs crap, you might want to tell the user instead of silently failing. JavaScript supports regular expressions, in case you want to go for that. But anyhow, you want to deal with `parseInt()` failing.

JavaScript supports exception handling quite similar to Java with a `try-catch-finally`, you might want to go for that and tell the user about bogus input.

### The `required` attribute of `<input/>`

The `required` attribute of `<input/>` is for *form submission*. Because you use the `<input/>` element outside a form, there is no *form submission*, therefore the `required` attribute doesn't make sense.

### Indentation

Consistent indentation is paramount, and you follow it.
There is no official standard or convention for indentation in JavaScript.

While the community has taken a lot of rules from Java, including the 4 spaces indentation, some Software Craftsmen like Robert C. Martin suggest that indentation nowadays should actually be 2 spaces rather than 4.

### Strict mode

JavaScript is in its core ECMA-262, aka ECMAScript. Strictly speaking, JavaScript was Netscape's name for its implementation of ECMAScript.

ECMA-262 defines a *strict mode* (10.1.1) which can be enabled with the `use strict` directive. [The most notable differences are](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

- In *strict mode*, usage of the *future reserved words* `implements`, `interface`, `let`, `package`, `private`, `protected`, `public`, `static` and `yield` is an error. (7.6.1.2)
- Octal literals are *not* supported. (7.8.3)
- Octal escape sequences are *not* supported. (7.8.4)
- functions and variables declared `eval()` code must be declared within a new variable environment that is accessible to the eval code only. (10.4.2.1)
- The `delete` operator is limited. (11.4.1)
- Assignment are stricter. (11.13.1)
- `eval` and `arguments` are not allowed as variable names (12.2.1), including exception variables (12.14.1).
- `with` is not allowed. (12.10)
  A full list can be seen in Annex C.

You might want to make it a habit to program in *strict mode* always. It ensures greater compatibility of your source code with future language directions.

Comment: I don't think it is ambiguous at all. It is HTML5, as marked by the header. Self-closing input elements **[are valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)**. I really wish that you correct your answer, because it is otherwise very good.

Comment: Also, let me suggest the site http://developers.whatwg.org/ for your use as reference, instead of W3Schools. Example: http://developers.whatwg.org/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type

Comment: I don't refer to W3Schools. Never did. And never will. And the header does not say it's HTML5. The header says it's HTML, and the HTML5 specification says that's allowed for HTML5. The HTML5 specification does not say that this header discriminates it as HTML5 from all other versions of HTML and XHTML.

Comment: re: w3c, it was my mistake; I apologise.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` does not unambiguously declare HTML5. The combination of `<!DOCTYPE html>` served as `Content-Type: text/html` suggests nowadays that it is HTML5. `<!DOCTYPE html>` can also be used for XHTML, and `<!DOCTYPE html>` served as `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` would be XHTML5. `<!DOCTYPE html>` is, from a perspective of SGML and XML, no way precise enough to claim that it is HTML5 and HTML5 only. Actually, `<!DOCTYPE html>` precisely means this: "some form of HTML without further formal declaration".

Comment: It may be misleading to say that JS and Java were "born together". Perhaps describing the camelCase naming pattern as an accepted best practice and omitting Java entirely is more appropriate. It's not the bible but a decent reference: [Google JS Style Guide: Naming](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Naming#Naming)

Comment: **Naming Conventions**: JS and Java have absolutely nothing in common (beside the first 4 letters). Also there is no `camelCase` convention for either language. If camelCase or not - just be consistent in the naming of variables/objects in the whole project! **Local vs Global Variables**: Is partly wrong because Javascript has no block level scope but a function level scope. The `var i` from the `for(...)` loop will automatically be "moved" to the beginning of the function -> [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var-hoisting)

Comment: There is a `camelCase` convention for the names of methods and non-constant variables Java, as described in the *SUN Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language*. I also often say myself that besides J A V A, Java and JavaScript have nothing in common - but only to ppl who are mixing things up. There was some form of cooperation in the language and API design between Netscape and SUN back then, which is the reason for Java being in both names, and also some things in the API being the same or at least similar. Some had this vision of JavaScript being the scripting language for Java.

Comment: You're right about JavaScript having function scope only, I'll fix that. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript): "_JavaScript, despite the name, is essentially unrelated to the Java programming language, although both have the common C syntax, and JavaScript copies many Java names and naming conventions. The language was originally named "LiveScript" but was renamed in a co-marketing deal between Netscape and Sun, in exchange for Netscape bundling Sun's Java runtime with their then-dominant browser. The key design principles within JavaScript are inherited from the Self and Scheme programming languages._" + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/

Comment: note that you will probably not have a good time if you expect XML semantics to work in (X)HTML5 — for example, `<script src="foo.js"/>` will not do what you think.

Comment: @Eevee at least with Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Rekonq it does exactly what I think and expect. It executes the script from file foo.js. What do you think I think it does?

Comment: pardon, should've have included that X.  if your document is read as regular ol' HTML5, the `/` will be ignored and the entire rest of your document (at least until the next `</script>`) will be parsed as script content, then discarded

Comment: That's true. Although relevant browsers no longer do that. Still, if one wants to be on the safe side, the XML serializer creating the XHTML document could be configured to output StartTag EndTag instead of EmptyElemTag for those elements where the EmptyElemTag would confuse, like `<script/>` for example, but EmptyElemTag where StartTag EndTag would confuse, like `<br/>` and `<hr/>` for example. But that's only required for old browsers, if it was decided to support them and the XHTML is sent as `text/html` instead of `application/xhtml+xml`, which is a workaround for such old browsers.

Comment: "The usage of the empty element tag syntax `<input ... />` suggests (not mandates) that it's XHTML" <- Repeating this over and over is not going to make it any more true than it was when you said it the first time.  Send the source through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and see what it says.  "Error found while checking this document as HTML5!" (hint: and it's not because of the self closing tags).  While you do make some good points, the rest of your review is controversial BS as the others have already pointed out.  It's unclear as to why the "Strict Mode" section is relevant.

Comment: @cimmanon I hope you're aware that XHTML5 is a subset of the permissable HTML5 syntaxes. That the validator does not say anything about this might also be because it is still *experimental*. Even if the final version wouldn't mean anything. The point is making the already started polyglot syntax complete and not breaking it so that the HTML5 file would be XHTML5 and could be processed with XML tools.

Comment: I feel that this discussion of the differences between HTML5 and XHTML5 and whatnot is unnecessary; I haven't heard of XHTML since the days of HTML 4.0. You even say that the current code could be XHTML5 with the right Content-Type header, so the code is not incorrect. Why pontificate on these obscure, mostly irrelevant issues to a beginning programmer?

Comment: I think it's relevant whether you can process your stuff with XML tools or can't. It's not obscure, it's simple. And why not learn things the right way from the start (as people should've already done in the past when HTML was an SGML application). Now with XHTML being defined as an XML application, things have become simpler. And the polyglot syntax is simpler to parse than the HTML5 syntax, so why not use it. Except for "I want to be sloppy" I haven't heard any good argument against writing HTML5 as XHTML5 in polyglot syntax yet.

Comment: Those are valid points, but most people won't be parsing their own code (a full-fledged HTML parser is often necessary anyway), and if there's nothing incompatible with XHTML in this code, I don't feel it's worth mentioning. I understand what you mean — that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 14):

Your JS has a few problems.  In the first place, you should always define your variables with the `var` keyword, or you can have major problems debugging your program ([using var to declare variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485439/2509848)):

```
sumofnums = 0;
```

should become:

```
var sumofnums = 0;
```

You do your braces correctly, but `sumofnums` would be easier to read as `sumOfNums`.  Also, [JSLint](http://jslint.com) thinks we should merge the first two `var` declarations.  Additionally, you should use a four spaces per level of indentation, not two:

```
function sum() {
    var sumOfNums = 0, nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");

    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sumOfNums += parseInt(nums[i]);
    }

    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sumOfNums;
}
```

Comment: I'd say whether indentation is 4 spaces or 2 spaces is rather a matter of taste, as there is no official convention for that regarding (X)HTML and JavaScript, AFAIK.

Comment: 4 is pretty standard across most of the development world: in cases where there's no other standard, it's a safe default

Comment: Even more important would be to localize `i`.

Answer (score 11):

You have a problem in your HTML, according to the [official validator at W3C](http://validator.w3.org/check):

This is not valid:

```
<script lang="javascript">
```

It should be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Because `lang` attributes are supposed to specify the language of the webpage, they are not allowed to be longer than 8 characters, according to the W3C validator: **Bad value javascript for attribute lang on element script: Subtags must not exceed 8 characters in length.**

The correct use for this attribute would be to use it as this for a Spanish webpage:

```
lang="es"
```

In American English:

```
lang="en-us"
```

Comment: Just to be precise, the `lang` attribute specifies the language of the element content. This only happens to be the entire page if the `lang` attribute appears on the root element (which usually is `<html/>`). But it can also be used for mixing languages within a single document.

Comment: I think it was a botched attempt to use the [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8734372/1157100) `<script language="javascript">` syntax of HTML 3.2.

Answer (score 10):

Comments w.r.t the algo and not the javascript practises:

- Don't trust the user. Suppose I enter`,` or `0,`, shouldn't you provide me 0 rather than NaN?
- Provide valid error message for error conditions like empty input or invalid cases as above.
- Does parseInt take care of characters? Does it throw exceptions? Should you catch it in the outer loop? Should you provide any error message or continue by ignoring it?

Answer (score 6):

Referencing this [informative post](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2010/a-minimal-html5-document/), there are a number of issues with your HTML5:

1. There's a [potential security flaw](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) if you do not include an encoding. All content on the page is decoded using the specified encoding. If the decoding uses the wrong charset it may lead to scripts with errors, and allow unexpected consequences with things like cross-site-references when URL's are decoded differently depending on system defaults and expectations. For example, [Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/dec/google-xss-example) shows how a mismatch between the actual encoding of the page, and the way the system interprets the page, can lead to XSS attack vectors. Specifying the encoding as part of the page header would remove that vector.
2. For accessibility reasons you should include the language

Your header for the HTML5 should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Sum of two numbers</title>
</head>
.....
```

Comment: The question clearly was XHTML. Your answer is HTML. You should fix your answer to match the question.

Comment: @ChristianHujer - I am not convinced. The DOCTYPE is for HTML5, (for XHTML it would need to be: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` ). The question is tagged `html` and not `xhtml`. Are you sure?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, it is a guess based on the usage of `EmptyElemTag` `<input ... */>*`.

Comment: `<input ... />` can be used in HTML5, I don't know why it would make it XHTML. I think DOCTYPE is more important than EmptyElemTag. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#void

Comment: <input.../> makes this part HTML5 polyglot, which is HTML5 and XHTML5 at the same time (just XML Namespace is missing). And there's no reason to break the XML-compatible Polyglot syntax by adding non-XML stuff for no reason.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of the security flaw?

Answer (score 6):

`parseInt` only allows integers and truncates all decimal entries, so entering `.5,.5` throws a `NaN`, and `0.5,0.5` returns 0 instead of 1. Either modify your instructions to tell the user you only accept integers or (even better) change to `parseFloat` to allow non-integer numbers.

Answer (score 5):

#### Header

There are things you can do to improve your header. This:

```
<head>
  <title>Sum of two numbers</title>
</head>
```

Should at least have this added for a charset:

```
<head>
  <title>Sum of two numbers</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

#### CSS

You could use some CSS to improve/customize how your documented is presented. This would make it where it would look more similar across browsers/platforms. For example:

```
<body style="font-family: Times New Roman, serif; font-color: black;">
```

You could also make it into a separate .CSS file, so if you added more documents it would be reused.

```
<link href="my-pretty-website.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: The question clearly was XHTML. Your answer is HTML. You should fix your answer to match the question.

Comment: @ChristianHujer You should probably delete all your comments about the question being XHTML when it's clearly HTML5 (according to the DOCTYPE).

Comment: Specifying the foreground color without specifying the background color is a very bad habit. If the user has a user stylesheet which defines foreground white and background black, and you only define foreground black, the user gets black on black - nice!

Comment: Plus, the CSS property name for the foreground color is `color`, not `font-color`.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok `<!DOCTYPE html>` does not claim that it's HTML5. The very same can be used for XHTML5 as well.

Comment: @ChristianHujer I was only pointing out what you said. Which was "The question clearly was XHTML." This is not true, which is exactly what you clarify in your answer.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Yup. But still, the question was clearly XHTML in the sense that it used the Polyglot syntax of HTML5 which is XML-compatible and therefore XHTML5 at the same time. No reason to break that.

Comment: @ChristianHujer What's XHTML5? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Yes, and that answer is wrong, Rob's comment on that answer is correct.

Comment: It is recommended to place `<meta charset="…">` as early as possible, since it affects the interpretation of everything else, including the title.

Answer (score 5):

If you go very deep into details of programming with all finesse, amongst all the things that the others have mentioned, always use `++i` over `i++` if it's the third argument of `for` loops.

The reason is actually a bit tricky to explain for people not yet deeply into programming, especially in JavaScript, since it's lacking the *call by reference* concept that'd come in handy for the explaination. But I'll try:

`i++` and `++i` are unary operators. They are compiled into (or in case of JavaScript interpreted as) statements what to do with the variable value. While `++i` increases the value and then uses the new value of `i`, `i++` first uses the value of `i` but then increases it afterwards.

Imagine these operators were functions with a return value, and furthermore that these functions were able to modify the value of their arguments in a way that these changes persisted even if you leave the function again. That concept is called *call by reference*. Now, with this concept, we can have a look at how the unary operators would look like.

First the one for `++i`:

```
function operatorPlusPlusVar ( i ) {
    i = i + 1; // Assign the new, incremented value to i
    return i; // Return the new value
}
```

Now the one for `i++`:

```
function operatorVarPlusPlus ( i ) {
    var oldValue = i;
    i = i + 1; // Assign the new, incremented value to i
    return oldValue; // Return the old value
}
```

As you can see, the `i++` statement needs to store the original value of i so it can return the old value in spite of i having its new value assigned to it already when leaving the function. That means, on execution, you need one to find a space in the RAM to store the old value (`var oldValue`), and then copy the old value to that memory spot (`= i`), on top of everything that `++i` has to do as well.

Since the third part of a `for` loop is executed after the loop's body was run, and you're not using the return value of the `++` operator (you want i to be incremented, you don't care what the `++` statement itself returns since you don't use its return value), you're basically wasting memory and run time if you use `i++` instead of `++i`.

Does that show in performance? No, not in this example. Does it show in memory usage? No, not in this example. Why am I telling you this, then? Because I hope to motivate you to always look under the hood of programming, and it's never wrong to know *exactly* what you do and why. Cheers and a happy new year!

Comment: Most compilers and runtime environments today are smart enough to see that the value of `i` in `i++` is not used and therefore compile / interpret `i++` as if it were written `++i`. This is verified with GCC (4.5.2 with -O0), javac (you can use javap -c to see) and Keil C251 (a Compiler which is known to be crap otherwise). So, while what you're writing is technically correct, it is irrelevant today and a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 4):

## Strict mode

The first JS suggestion is always to set your JS scripts to *[strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651415/what-is-strict-mode-and-how-is-it-used)* by making their first line `"use strict";`.

This will immediately avoid such problems as your accidental pollution of the global namespace, for example.

## JSLint

Then pass your JS code through JSLint, and address its suggestions.

## Number parsing

Your number parsing is not very solid.

I suggest using the unary operator +: `var number = + nums[i]; sumofnums += number;`, but there are many options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

JSLint recommends the following:

> JSLint does not recommend use of the `for` statement. Use array methods like `forEach` instead. The `for` option will suppress some warnings. The forms of `for` that JSLint accepts are restricted, excluding the new ES6 forms.

The `reduce` method would be best in this situation:

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Sum of two numbers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Enter any amount of numbers separated by a comma:</h1>
  <input id="nums" type="text" required="required" />
  <button onclick="sum()">Get sum</button>
  <h3 id="sum"></h3>

  <script lang="javascript">
    function reducer(accumulator, current) {
      return Number(accumulator) + Number(current);
      }
    
    function sum() {
      var nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");
      var sumofnums = nums.reduce(reducer);
      document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sumofnums;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**References**

- [JSLint: Help](http://jslint.com/help.html#for)
- [Array.prototype.reduce() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)